# Showing both boxplots when using split in seaborn violinplots

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot, violin-plot

I would like to make split violin plots which also show the boxplots for both datasets, like in the figure of the question [Seaborn: How to apply custom color to each seaborn violinplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70442958/seaborn-how-to-apply-custom-color-to-each-seaborn-violinplot) , problem is that when using split seaborn shows only one of them (and it's not even clear to me to which dataset it refers to) as you can see in the answer, is there a way to overcome this or should I use a different package?

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Seaborn uses a thick line with a little white circle when `inner='box'`. A full boxplot usually doesn't look well.   Your statement *"when using split seaborn shows only one of them"* is a misunderstanding: seaborn uses both datasets combined (when `inner='box'`). You could use e.g. `inner='quartiles'` when you need the inner part to be different for both halves.  See also https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2742

Comment: See also [Can you have a box plot overlap a half violin plot on a raincloud plot using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67376683/can-you-have-a-box-plot-overlap-a-half-violin-plot-on-a-raincloud-plot-using-pyt) for some inspiration if you really need half boxplots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with an artificial dataset to show how the default `inner='box'` shows a simple boxplot-like box for the combined dataset.

The second plot shows how `inner='quartile'` looks like.

The rightmost plot shows an approach to explicitly draw separate boxplots (using `width=` to place them close to the center).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'Value': (np.random.randn(4, 100).cumsum(axis=0) + np.array([[15], [5], [12], [7]])).ravel(),
                     'Set': np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 100),
                     'x': np.repeat([1, 2], 200)})
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(15, 4))

palette = ['paleturquoise', 'yellow']
sns.violinplot(data=data, x='x', y='Value', hue='Set', split=True, inner='box', palette=palette, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('Default, inner="box"')

sns.violinplot(data=data, x='x', y='Value', hue='Set', split=True, inner='quartiles', palette=palette, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('Using inner="quartiles"')

sns.violinplot(data=data, x='x', y='Value', hue='Set', split=True, inner=None, palette=palette, ax=ax3)
sns.boxplot(data=data, x='x', y='Value', hue='Set', color='white', width=0.3, boxprops={'zorder': 2}, ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title('Explicitely drawing boxplots')
handles, labels = ax3.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax3.legend(handles[:2], labels[:2], title='Set')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.violinplot, split with separate boxplots]

Comment: Thank you! The rightmost plot is indeed the closest thing to what I've been trying to do