# How to customize seaborn boxplot with specific color sequence when boxplots have hue

Tags: python, colors, seaborn, boxplot

I want to make boxplots with hues but I want to color code it so that each specific X string is a certain color with the hue just being a lighter color. I am able to do a boxplot without a hue. When I incorporate the hue, I get the second boxplot which loses the colors. Can someone help me customize the colors for the figure that contains the hue?

Essentially, its what the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70442958/seaborn-how-to-apply-custom-color-to-each-seaborn-violinplot) is but with boxplots.

This is my code:
first boxplot

```
order=['Ash1','E1A','FUS','p53']
colors=['gold','teal','darkorange','royalblue']
color_dict=dict(zip(order,colors))
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(25,15))
bp=sns.boxplot(data=df_idrs, x=df_idrs["construct"], y=df_idrs['Norm_Ef_IDR/Ef_GS'],ax=ax,palette=color_dict)
sns.stripplot(ax=ax,y='Norm_Ef_IDR/Ef_GS', x='construct', data=df_idrs,palette=color_dict, 
                      jitter=1, marker='o', alpha=0.4,edgecolor='black',linewidth=1, dodge=True)
ax.axhline(y=1,linestyle="--",color='black',linewidth=2)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.03, 1))
```

second boxplot

```
order=['Ash1','E1A','FUS','p53']
colors=['gold','teal','darkorange','royalblue']
color_dict=dict(zip(order,colors))
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(25,15))
bp=sns.boxplot(data=df_idrs, x=df_idrs["construct"], y=df_idrs['Norm_Ef_IDR/Ef_GS'],ax=ax, hue=df_idrs["location"])
sns.stripplot(y='Norm_Ef_IDR/Ef_GS', x='construct', data=df_idrs, hue=df_idrs["location"], 
                      jitter=1, marker='o', alpha=0.4,edgecolor='black',linewidth=1, dodge=True)
ax.axhline(y=1,linestyle="--",color='black',linewidth=2)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.03, 1))
```

The only thing that changed was the palette to hue. I have seen many examples on here but I am unable to get them to work. Using the second code, I have tried the following:
Nothing happens for this one.

```
for ind, bp in enumerate(ax.findobj(PolyCollection)):
    rgb = to_rgb(colors[ind // 2])
    if ind % 2 != 0:
        rgb = 0.5 + 0.5 * np.array(rgb)  # make whiter
    bp.set_facecolor(rgb)
```

I get index out of range for the following one.

```
for i in range(0,4):
    mybox = bp.artists[i]
    mybox.set_facecolor(color_dict[order[i]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib stores the boxes in `ax.patches`, but there are also 2 dummy patches (used to construct the legend) that need to be filtered away.  The dots of the `stripplot` are stored in `ax.collections`. There are also 2 dummy collections for the legend, but as those come at the end, they don't form a problem.

Some remarks:

- `sns.boxplot` returns the subplot on which it was drawn; as it is called with `ax=ax` it will return that same `ax`
- Setting `jitter=1`in the `stripplot` will smear the dots over a width of `1`. `1` is the distance between the x positions, and the boxes are only `0.4` wide. To avoid clutter, the code below uses `jitter=0.4`.

Here is some example code starting from dummy test data:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgb
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20230215)
order = ['Ash1', 'E1A', 'FUS', 'p53']
colors = ['gold', 'teal', 'darkorange', 'royalblue']
hue_order = ['A', 'B']

df_idrs = pd.DataFrame({'construct': np.repeat(order, 200),
                        'Norm_Ef_IDR/Ef_GS': (np.random.normal(0.03, 1, 800).cumsum() + 10) / 15,
                        'location': np.tile(np.repeat(hue_order, 100), 4)})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))

sns.boxplot(data=df_idrs, x=df_idrs['construct'], y=df_idrs['Norm_Ef_IDR/Ef_GS'], hue='location',
            order=order, hue_order=hue_order, ax=ax)
box_colors = [f + (1 - f) * np.array(to_rgb(c))  # whiten colors depending on hue
              for c in colors for f in np.linspace(0, 0.5, len(hue_order))]
box_patches = [p for p in ax.patches if isinstance(p, PathPatch)]
for patch, color in zip(box_patches, box_colors):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)

sns.stripplot(y='Norm_Ef_IDR/Ef_GS', x='construct', data=df_idrs, hue=df_idrs['location'],
              jitter=0.4, marker='o', alpha=0.4, edgecolor='black', linewidth=1, dodge=True, ax=ax)
for collection, color in zip(ax.collections, box_colors):
    collection.set_facecolor(color)

ax.axhline(y=1, linestyle='--', color='black', linewidth=2)
handles = [tuple(box_patches[i::len(hue_order)]) for i in range(len(hue_order))]
ax.legend(handles=handles, labels=hue_order, title='hue category',
          handlelength=4, handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None, pad=0)},
          loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: boxplot with hue and individual colors]